# ASP.NET C# gridview RowIndex does not work

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I am trying to use `RowIndex` to automatically update a column called `Length` in a SQL Server table that is directly related to the `LengthID` column (don't ask why but this is just for cosmetic reasons for the website).

This works for insert using `SELECT MAX(ID)`, but to work for update, I need the rowindex but intellisense does not recognise it and it is just underlined with squiggles.

I have specified `using System.Web.UI.WebControls;`. Having trawled Stackoverflow, CodeProject, etc. for two days I have not yet got one solution to work!

Latest attempt:

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
int id = Int32.Parse(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
```

This must be something terribly obvious but I am blind to it.

Comment: Well - does the `GridView1` actually *define* a value for the `DataKeys` property?

Comment: Yes DataKeyNames="CID" DataSourceID="SqlDataAssets" CID = ID

Comment: Thanks marc_s you pointed me in the right direction. Code now works using these lines instead:                                                                                                                                int rowIndex = ((sender as Button).NamingContainer as GridViewRow).RowIndex;
int curId = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[rowIndex].Values[0]);